# Почему оба метода сортирую массив по алфавиту, ведь первый метод должен сортировать его по длине строк?

Tags: java, массивы, сортировка

```
public class Sort {
    String temp;
    int rez;

    //метод сортировки по длине строки
    void GetSortLeng(String mas[]) {
        for (String i : mas) {
            for (int j = 0; j < mas.length - 1; j++) {
                if (mas[j].compareTo(mas[j + 1]) > 0) {
                    temp = mas[j];
                    mas[j] = mas[j + 1];
                    mas[j + 1] = temp;
                }
            }
        }

        for (String i : mas)
            System.out.print(i + " ");
    }

    //метод сортировки по алфовиту
    void GetSortWord(String mas[]) {
        for (String i : mas) {
            for (int j = 0; j < mas.length - 1; j++) {
                for (int g = 0; g < mas[j].length() && g < mas[j + 1].length(); g++) {
                    if (mas[j].charAt(g) > mas[j + 1].charAt(g)) {
                        temp = mas[j];
                        mas[j] = mas[j + 1];
                        mas[j + 1] = temp;
                        break;
                    } else if (mas[j].charAt(g) < mas[j + 1].charAt(g)) break;
                    else if ((mas[j].indexOf(mas[j + 1])) >= 0) {
                        temp = mas[j];
                        mas[j] = mas[j + 1];
                        mas[j + 1] = temp;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        for (String i : mas) 
            System.out.print(i + " ");
    }
}

class Prog101 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String mask[] = {"this", "is", "a", "in", "can", "string"};
        Sort ST = new Sort();
        System.out.println("Sortirovka po dlinne: ");
        ST.GetSortLeng(mask);
        System.out.println("\n\nSortirovka po alfovitu:");
        ST.GetSortWord(mask);
    }
}
```

Comment: вы сравниваете сами строки, а не их длину. должно быть что-то вроде `mas[j].length()>mas[j + 1].length()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод `java.lang.String#compareTo` сравнивает строки не только по длине, но также и лексически.
То есть если мы сравним две строки `"b"` и `"a"`  (`"b".compareTo("a")`), то получим значение `1`, а не `0` как если бы мы сравнивали по длине.

Для того чтобы сравнивнить по длине Вам необходимо изменить метод следующим образом:

```
void GetSortLeng(String mas[]) {
    for (String i : mas) {
        for (int j = 0; j < mas.length - 1; j++) {
            if (mas[j].length() > mas[j + 1].length()) {
                temp = mas[j];
                mas[j] = mas[j + 1];
                mas[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    for (String i : mas)
        System.out.print(i + " ");
}
```

В результате получите:

```
Sortirovka po dlinne: 
a is in can this string
```